# Selecting multiple data from a database through PHP

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a search form that is able to retrieve the username of a user, however I can't figure out how to get it to return more than that, I want it to display the first names and last names too.

Below is the code at the minute that works, but when I try and add in more variables, for example  `if ($stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE ?"))` then it doesn't return anything at all and asks to insert a search query.

I have also tried  `if ($stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE %?%"))` and `LIKE "%?%"))`, but no results.

**search.php**

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['searchsubmit']))
{
    include 'searchform.php';
        $name=$_POST['name'];
         if ($stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE ?")) 
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($personresult);
            $stmt->fetch();
            ?>
            <center>
                <BR>
                <h1>Search Results are as follows:</h1>
                <h2>USERNAMES</h2>
                <BR>
            <?php

            print_r($personresult);
               ?>
            </center>
            <?php
        } 
        else
        { 
            echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
        } 
    }
 else 
    {
     echo "NOT SET!";
     }
```

Comment: The part between `select` and `from` is what you are selecting. So with `select Username FROM users WHERE Username LIKE ?` you only select `username`, add the columns you want in that list separated by commas. If your username is not exact than you need to append `%`s on your variable `$name`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I've tried using * and selecting more, but that didnt work. The code above is what I have currently working.

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Comment: The more fields you select the more you will have to bind in the results otherwise it will fail - so selecting all fields in the query means you would need to bind all fields in variables in the `bind_result()` ~ from the manual `"Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Depending on column types bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type. "`

Comment: It simply doesnt display anything at all. So do i add more s's and $name's in to the bind_param function?

Comment: Ah I see, is this correct? $name=$_POST['%name%'];

Comment: You are only supplying one variable into the sql so you only need one 's' with which you bind the param - it is, as far as I know, in the `bind_result` that you would need to reference other fields

Comment: Chris how would I append the %'s to my $name variable?

Comment: Use the `@` to tag users. `$stmt->bind_param('s', '%' . $name .  '%');`

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling `Username` .. You need to be calling `*`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE ?
```

This is my personal script I use:

```
<?php

$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "db_user";
$dbpassword = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
$username = $_POST["username"];
}
if (!empty($_POST["password"])) {
$password = $_POST["password"];
}

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row["Username"] . " " . $row["Firstname"] . " " .  $row["Lastname"] . "<br>";
if ($row["Username"] == $username && $row["Password"] == $password) {
            echo "success";
            // do more stuff here like set session etc
        } else {
            $echo "incorrect username and/or password";
        }
     }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry yes I should have mentioned I've tried using multiple, and using *, but it doesn't work

Comment: That is the exact code I use for my username script minus a couple of things I won't display for security purposes of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the statement object with mysqli_stmt_init?

See [mysqli_stmt_init](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php) and [mysqli-stmt.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

> If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement,
>   PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error
>   handling)

add this line in `connection.php` right after creating connection object:

```
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

At least, you can trace possible errors

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    include 'connection.php';
    if( isset( $_POST['searchsubmit'] ) ) {

        include 'searchform.php';
        $name=$_POST['name'];

        if ( $stmt = $connection->prepare ("SELECT `Username`,`firstname`,`lastname` FROM `users` WHERE `Username` LIKE ?") ) {
            /* not 100% sure about whether this is required here like this or not but usually a like expression uses '%' as a wildcard */

            $var='%'.$name'.%';
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $var );

            $res=$stmt->execute();
            /* 3 columns selected in query, 3 columns bound in results */
            $stmt->bind_result( $personresult, $firstname, $lastname );

            if( $res ){

                $stmt->fetch();

                echo "
                    <center>
                        <BR>
                        <h1>Search Results are as follows:</h1>
                        <h2>USERNAMES</h2><!-- 3 columns/variables -->
                        {$personresult},{$firstname},{$lastname}
                        <BR>
                    </center>";
            }

        } else { 
            echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
        }
    } else {
        echo "NOT SET!";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just asks me to enter a search query